# "Save all comments" button on a Pull Request

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

When you create a pull request on TFS you have a button called 'Save all comments'. When I press the button, nothing happens.

You can find the button on the overview page pressing the '...' menu.

[image: dropdown menu]

We expected to have a download with all the comments, maybe someone can shine some light on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This button is not to download the comments, but to give you the ability to write a few different comments and in one click to save all.

For example, I write 2 comments (and don't save each comment):

[image]

Now I click the button:

[image]

Comment: Clear answer. Sounds logically, but I don't understand why you just dont add the comment after you wrote the comment

Comment: @Mario good question, I always click "Comment" after I write a comment...

Comment: This is a good answer, but it leaves me hanging in one way: Is there a way to download all the comments?

Comment: @CPomerantz Maybe with the Rest API.

Comment: I wonder if the use-case for the Save All Comments (versus clicking Comment after each) is to send all comments at once instead of piecemeal. With the latter option the pull request author might start making updates based on your first comment before you've created all your comments.

Comment: @Anssssss that is precisely why, I believe. Gitlab has a similar feature, which is actually superior to the way Azure DevOps does it. You save each comment as you type it, and then you submit them all at once. With Azure DevOps, you're in danger of losing your work in progress as a reviewer.